# How to fix this: WARNING: > Speaker "engine_speaker": Impossible to play ''. Make sure the file format is supported

Tags: webots

The full warning is
WARNING: Invalid URL 'C:/Users/xxxxx/OneDrive/Documents/my_Webots_learning/controllers/autonomous_vehicle/'. Sounds must be in '.mp3' or '.wav' format.
WARNING: MyMicro_Car "vehicle(1)" > Speaker "engine_speaker": Impossible to play ''. Make sure the file format is supported (8 or 16 bits, mono or stereo wave).

I have made my own vehicle proto from the Car robot and use the autonomous vehicle controller. Everything works for the most part, I am driving manually until I can learn to program the autonomous behavior, but this warning fills the console repeatedly and no sound is played. I don't think I have altered anything relating to the engine speaker, but I can't figure out where the speaker file is specified. It is not in the Car proto nor the autonomous vehicle controller as far as I can find. I do not needs sounds, just want the warning to stop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's an `engine speaker`?

Answer (score 0):

This warning tells you that no sound file is found for your model.

You should copy the `sounds` directory from the Webots installation path `$WEBOTS_HOME/projects/vehicles/protos/sounds` in your project path `C:/Users/xxxxx/OneDrive/Documents/my_Webots_learning/worlds/sounds` or in the same folder as you vehicle PROTO model.

Note that the `Car` PROTO has the field `engineSound`, so to suppress the warning you could also clear it and set it to "". This will disable the speaker and the warning.

*Disclaimer: I am a software developer at Webots.*